# copying files from one directory to another using filters

Tags: linux, bash, aws

I have these files in my source folder

```
source_path/date=20191230/somefile.txt
source_path/date=20191231/somefile.txt
source_path/date=20200101/somefile.txt
source_path/date=20200102/somefile.txt
```

If I do the bellow command all files will be copied to my dest_path folder

```
cp --recursive source_path/date=20200* dest_path/
```

It works perfectly in my local machine

I just get copy these files to my dest_path as i wanted

```
source_path/date=20200101/somefile.txt
source_path/date=20200102/somefile.txt
```

The problem comes when I replicate this same thing in aws.
I am copying from S3 to my Ec2 instance with this comand

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://source_path/date=20200* home/ec2-user/dest_path/
```

This does not work nor gives a error
it just gives this output

```
0.35user 0.05system 0:00.48elapsed 85%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 50660maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+17977minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: I think that this is not a question about the Unix&Linux shell and also I think you can get an answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834708/how-can-i-use-wildcards-to-cp-a-group-of-files-with-the-aws-cli)

Comment: @ thanasisp Thankyou very much you just saved my weekend!!! This is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [punkrockpolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2596608/punkrockpolly)'s [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834779/4957508) (spotted by [thanasisp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/216907/thanasisp)):

---

To download multiple files from an aws bucket to your current directory, you can use `recursive`, `exclude`, and `include` flags.
**The order of the parameters matters.**

Example command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://data/ . --recursive --exclude "*" --include "2016-08*"
```

For more info on how to use these filters: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters